# VueJs - Password managers detection

Tags: vue.js, password-manager

I am developing a new commercial project using VueJS (Vue 2).
For Authentication we're using backend jwt tokens and front end VvueJs Route Guards.
I noticed that after logging in, password managers do not detect it, i.e. offer to save the password. While they do for any other site. The password managers are LastPass and BitWarden.

Is there anything specific that they're looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the password input element have something other than `type="password"`? Are you turning off autocomplete on the `form` element (ex: `autocomplete="off"`)? Either of those could prevent it from working. Running the site from localhost may prevent certain password managers. They can also pick up context from the `name` you give the input field. Try setting the input `name` to `password` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you hvaughan3, I checked the names and they were fine. Found the problem, it wasn't an actual form. Once I turned it into a form it sorted the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this, the issue was that it was not an actual form. Once I turned it into a form with a submit button it resovled the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).